# Prevent MSTest from copying / deploying every dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mstest

When running MSTest from Visual Studio - the unit test execution time is relatively quick.

When running MSTest from the command line, with /testsettings flag - the execution takes forever and that is because it spends 95% of its startup time copying the dll's to its Out folder. Is there a way to prevent this?

The default Local.testsettings in the project has no modifications to it (which also means it is empty). However, if I try to use that same file from the command line, MSTest complains about missing DLL's that the Unit Test reference.

Comment: 95% to copy a handful of DLLs?

Comment: Maybe more like 99% time copying dll's....

Comment: I will have to double check tomorrow, but I am pretty sure that testing within visual studio does copy the Dlls as well, but I might confuse the TFS behavior. What is the time difference between both runs?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried disabling deployment in the test settings?  When it is disabled, the tests should be run in-place rather than on copied assemblies.  (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475.aspx for details.)

Comment: How exactly is that done? I see an explanation of the settings files, but the example given is how to configure deployment of a specific file. I don't see any other links that might help with this specific task.

Comment: This doesn't seem to help, without Copy Local enabled for each reference the test fails to execute even with this setting present in runsettings.

Answer (score -2):

try MSTest.exe /noisolation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms182489.aspx

Comment: This definately helped - but does not resolve the problem. It still ends up copying all the dll's (with a startup time now down to 2 minutes). Also - MS's description of /noisolatio doesn't mean much ("Run tests within the MSTest.exe process. This choice improves test run speed but increases risk to the MSTest.exe process")

Comment: /noisolation is about process isolation, not deployment, which is what this question is asking about