# MS Visual Studio Unit Tests take forever to close - even if there's no code in the test

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, unit-testing

Why would this be happening?  I have a no code in my test:

```
[TestClass]
public class ApiClientTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void ApiTestSampleUseCase()
    {
        TestCleanup();
    }

    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        //DeleteUsers();
    }
}
```

Yet when I run this, it takes ~1 minute to complete.  It passes, it just takes forever.  I set a breakpoint after DeleteUsers and it gets hit immediately; the delay is after the test has completed.

Comment: Check your `bin` directory - for some incomprehensible reason, MSTest copies all referenced assemblies to a new directory _every_ time you run the tests. (These are safe to delete, though.) Maybe it does something else as well that causes it to slow down after many runs...

Comment: That did the trick.  Feel free to post this as the answer and I'll mark it accordingly.  Any idea how I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: Great; see below (I initially posted it as a comment because I felt it was a shot in the dark).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `bin` directory - for some incomprehensible reason, MSTest copies all referenced assemblies to a new directory every time you run the tests. (These are safe to delete, though.) Maybe it does something else as well that causes it to slow down after many runs... According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9081852/626853) and [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475.aspx), you can disable this behaviour.

I'd recommend switching to [NUnit](http://nunit.org/) if possible, preferrably in combination with [FluentAssertions](http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/) (due to the not insignificant number of weird design decisions in MSTest, such as this behaviour, the lack of easy-to-use parameterized tests, and the fact that a test will get run even if `[TestInitialize]` throws an exception).

Comment: Sweet - I'm converting everything over to Nunit + FA now.  Cheers :)